# Displaying query results on a web page - Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I'm developing a web app of an e-commerce and I'm stuck on how to display products.

I have all the products resulting from a query in an `ArrayList<Product>`, but I don't know how to display them.

I was thinking about using a table-like rectangle for every product, where there are displayed all the infos of that product, but I don't know what component I should use, because the `Grid` isn't what I'm looking for, I think. These tables should have an header and two columns, the first column that will show the "title" of the row (like name, description, price etc) and the second column the value of that product. I looked at the grid but it has a "column-major" order and I'm looking for a "row-major" one.

A solution I came up with could be using a `Panel` for every product, and inside this panel I could add `Labels` and `Buttons`, but it seems to me as a shortcut that does not utilize the potential of Vaadin.

Furthermore, how can I dynamic set the number of grids (or tables or whatever the component I could use will be) to be on a row in the browser window and avoiding the risk of the products to be displayed outside that window?

Comment: I don't see why the creation of your own custom component wouldn't be a good idea. You could define UI elements, styling, listeners or whatever on such a reusable component. Maybe you could also show how you worked out your `Panel` solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this solution.

I used a `gridLayout` to create a table displaying every information.

```
public class SearchResultsView extends VerticalLayout implements View {

    public static final String NAME = "results";

    SearchResultsView(String search, String brandToSearch, String instrumentTypeToSearch,
            String usedStatusToSearch, String productTypeToSearch){

        Authentication localAuth = (Authentication) UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("AUTH");
        User user = localAuth.getUser();

        Label labelTitle = new Label("Search results");
        labelTitle.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
        labelTitle.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_COLORED);
        labelTitle.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_LARGE);

        addComponent(labelTitle);
        setComponentAlignment(labelTitle, Alignment.TOP_LEFT);

        if(brandToSearch == null) {
            brandToSearch = "All";
        }

        if(instrumentTypeToSearch == null) {
            instrumentTypeToSearch = "All";
        }


        if(productTypeToSearch == null) {
            productTypeToSearch = "All";
        }

        if(usedStatusToSearch == null) {
            usedStatusToSearch = "0";
        }
        else {
            switch(usedStatusToSearch) {
            case "All":
                usedStatusToSearch = "0";
                break;
            case "Used":
                usedStatusToSearch = "true";
                break;
            case "Not used":
                usedStatusToSearch = "false";
                break;
            default:
                usedStatusToSearch = "0";
                break;
            }
        }

        Boolean searchStringIsVoid = true;
        if(!search.isEmpty()) {
            searchStringIsVoid = false;
        }

        List<Product> queryResults = new ArrayList<Product>();

        try {
            queryResults = dao.QueriesDAO.getProducts(searchStringIsVoid, search, brandToSearch, instrumentTypeToSearch, usedStatusToSearch, productTypeToSearch);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for(Product product : queryResults) {

            int cols = 2;
            int rows;

            switch(product.getProductType()) {
                case "s":
                    rows = 11;
                    break;
                case "p":
                    rows = 10;
                    break;
                case "c":
                    rows = 9;
                    break;
                default:
                    rows = 9;
                    break;
            }

            GridLayout productGrid = new GridLayout(cols, rows);
            productGrid.setSizeFull();
            productGrid.setMargin(true);

            Panel productInfo = new Panel();

            Label productName = new Label(product.getNome());
            productName.setStyleName("gridlayout-slot");
            productName.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productName.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H3);
            productGrid.addComponent(productName, 0, 0, cols - 1, 0);

            Label description = new Label("Description");
            description.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(description, 0, 1);
            TextArea descriptionText = new TextArea();
            descriptionText.setWidth(100, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
            descriptionText.setValue(product.getDescrizione());
            descriptionText.setReadOnly(true);
            productGrid.addComponent(descriptionText, 1, 1);

            Label weight = new Label("Weight");
            weight.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(weight, 0, 2);
            String peso = String.valueOf(product.getPeso()) + " Kg";
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(peso), 1, 2);

            Label brand = new Label("Brand");
            brand.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(brand, 0, 3);
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(product.getMarca().toString()), 1, 3);

            Label instrType = new Label("Instrument type");
            instrType.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(instrType, 0, 4);
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(product.getClassificazione().toString()), 1, 4);

            Label usedStatus = new Label("Used status");
            usedStatus.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(usedStatus, 0, 5);
            String usedString = (product.isUsato()) ? "Used" : "Not used";
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(usedString), 1, 5);

            Label date = new Label("Insertion date");
            date.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(date, 0, 6);
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(product.getDataInserimento().toString()), 1, 6);

            Label price = new Label("Price");
            price.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
            productGrid.addComponent(price, 0, 7);
            java.util.Formatter unitaryPrice = new java.util.Formatter();
            String priceToString = unitaryPrice.format("%.2f", product.getPrezzo()).toString() + " €";
            productGrid.addComponent(new Label(priceToString), 1, 7);
            unitaryPrice.close();

            if(product.getProductType().equals("p")) {
                //rows == 10

                Label applicableDiscount = new Label("Applicable discount");
                applicableDiscount.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
                productGrid.addComponent(applicableDiscount, 0, rows - 2);

                String discountValueToString = String.valueOf(product.getSconto()) + "%";
                Label applicableDiscountValue = new Label(discountValueToString);
                productGrid.addComponent(applicableDiscountValue, 1, rows - 2);

            }
            else if(product.getProductType().equals("s")) {
                //rows == 11

                Label levelSuggested = new Label("Suggested level");
                levelSuggested.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
                productGrid.addComponent(levelSuggested, 0, rows - 3);

                String levelSuggestedValueToString = product.getLivelloConsigliato().toString();
                Label levelSuggestedValue = new Label(levelSuggestedValueToString);
                productGrid.addComponent(levelSuggestedValue, 1, rows - 3);

                Label applicableDiscount = new Label("Applicable discount");
                applicableDiscount.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_BOLD);
                productGrid.addComponent(applicableDiscount, 0, rows - 2);

                String discountValueToString = String.valueOf(product.getSconto()) + "%";
                Label applicableDiscountValue = new Label(discountValueToString);
                productGrid.addComponent(applicableDiscountValue, 1, rows - 2);

            }

            Button addToCart = new Button("Add to cart");
            addToCart.addClickListener(e -> {
                user.getShoppingCart().addToCart(product);
                localAuth.setUser(user);
                UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("AUTH", localAuth);
                UI.getCurrent().getNavigator().navigateTo(CartView.NAME);
            });
            addToCart.setStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_FRIENDLY);
            addToCart.addStyleName(ValoTheme.BUTTON_ICON_ALIGN_RIGHT);
            addToCart.setIcon(VaadinIcons.PLUS_CIRCLE_O);
            productGrid.addComponent(addToCart, 0 , rows - 1, 1, rows - 1);

            productInfo.setContent(productGrid);

            productInfo.setSizeFull();

            addComponent(productInfo);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom component (just as you have described) to represent each product. Should you need grid to *compose* your result listing on the web page, you can add any component to a grid now.

https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.1/8.1.4/release-notes.html#enhancements
https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/component-renderer